# Kotlin lets-plot: minimal example

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, lets-plot

I would like to write a completely minimal example of lets-plot, which just saves png and doesn't use any frontend. For this, I created a "helloworld" Kotlin project in IntelliJ IDEA. Then I added Maven dependency org.jetbrains.lets-plot:lets-plot-common:2.1.0. Now if I try to import jetbrains.letsPlot.letsPlot, I get the error "Unresolved reference: letsPlot". Thus, the question is how to write the most minimal lets-plot example, without using any frontend and Gradle.

Comment: What is more minimal about using Maven instead of Gradle?

Comment: Check the lets-plot project examples for JVM, see this project README section: https://github.com/JetBrains/lets-plot-kotlin#lets-plot-in-jvm-and-kotlinjs-application

Comment: A more up-to-date, Gradle based example here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77466634/kotlin-how-to-import-lets-plot-in-idea/77468724#77468724

Answer (score 4):

The right dependencies are org.jetbrains.lets-plot:lets-plot-kotlin-jvm:3.0.2 (for API) and org.jetbrains.lets-plot:lets-plot-image-export:2.1.0 (to be able to export to raster). Now it works, and the resulting image in lets-plot-images directory.

The code:

```
import jetbrains.letsPlot.export.ggsave
import jetbrains.letsPlot.geom.geomPoint
import jetbrains.letsPlot.letsPlot

fun main() {
    val xs = listOf(0,  0.5, 1, 2)
    val ys = listOf(0, 0.25, 1, 4)
    val data = mapOf<String, Any>("x" to xs, "y" to ys)

    val fig = letsPlot(data) + geomPoint(
        color = "dark-green",
        size = 4.0
    ) { x = "x"; y = "y" }

    ggsave(fig, "plot.png")
}
```

The resulting image:
[image: plot]