# Kotlin: how to import Lets Plot in IDEA

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, lets-plot

I am new to Jetbrains IDEA editor. I have a console application project. How can I add Let's Plot library/package/what-do-you-call-it so I can plot some functions and export them to say SVG files?

I found this question helpful, however it does not show how to import it, only how to use it: [Kotlin lets-plot: minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69061887/kotlin-lets-plot-minimal-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IntelliJ: `File` -> `New Project` -> `Gradle` + `GradleDSL=Kotlin`

**Gradle - build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.20"
}

group = "org.mygroup"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation("org.jetbrains.lets-plot:lets-plot-kotlin-jvm:4.5.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.lets-plot:lets-plot-image-export:4.1.0")

    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}
```

**Sample driver**

```
import org.jetbrains.letsPlot.export.ggsave
import org.jetbrains.letsPlot.geom.geomPoint
import org.jetbrains.letsPlot.letsPlot

fun main() {
    val xs = listOf(0,  0.5, 1, 2)
    val ys = listOf(0, 0.25, 1, 4)
    val data = mapOf<String, Any>("x" to xs, "y" to ys)

    val fig = letsPlot(data) + geomPoint(
        color = "dark-green",
        size = 4.0
    ) { x = "x"; y = "y" }

    // save .svg file in the current dir
    ggsave(plot = fig, filename = "fig.svg", path = ".")
}
```