# How to use Lets-Plot for an app written with Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, lets-plot

**How can I use Lets-Plot in my Android App (using Jetpack Compose and IntelliJ)?**

Although there are a few answers around on the web, I cannot get it to run. Can anyone give me the following:

1. A very simple example for the MainActivity.kt file
2. The dependencies for the app's build.gradle.kts

**Problems I encountered so far:**

- There is a lets-plot-compose library here, but I have no idea how to use it: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.lets-plot/lets-plot-compose-android/1.0.1
- There is an example, but to get it to run, you need a native .so library file, which I could not find: https://github.com/JetBrains/lets-plot-compose-demos
- There a simple example of how to save a Lets-Plot plot to file, but if you run that on Android, the ggsave crashes the app: [Kotlin lets-plot: minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69061887/kotlin-lets-plot-minimal-example/77511035#77511035)

Comment: Did you check out https://github.com/JetBrains/lets-plot-skia ?

Comment: Yes, I checked it, and it compiles fine, but when I start the app, I get this message in the LogCat: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libskiko-android-arm64.so" not found"

Comment: Then perhaps file an issue in their issue tracker, with details of your environment (e.g., IDE, target device).

Comment: Try to checkout this repo : https://github.com/JetBrains/lets-plot-compose-demos and run apps. Do they fail as well?

Comment: @alshan I noticed you are probably one of the authors. I actually started with your lets-plot-compose-demos and the result is the same. I simply compile using latest version of Intellij and compile to an Android Samsung A32 and otherwise, it all works fine for other stuff. Do you know why it says "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libskiko-android-arm64.so" not found"? Do you think the .so files should be automatically be working with the demos?

Comment: For those who is interested, the situation has  been resolved here: https://github.com/JetBrains/lets-plot-compose-demos/issues/1